# Problem connecting Tor Browser

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, network-configuration

Good morning, I have trouble installing the Tor Browser. I have removed and reinstalled, I tested with versions prior to see if it was a problem with the new version, and to try to change the time as proposed by others who had problems, and even then I could solve the problem.

I copy the installation process of the network.

Thank you.

14 sept. 2016 9:48:19 a. m..900 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.

14 sept. 2016 9:48:19 a. m..900 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.

14 sept. 2016 9:48:19 a. m..900 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.

14 sept. 2016 9:48:19 a. m..900 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150

14 sept. 2016 9:48:19 a. m..900 [NOTICE] Renaming old configuration file to "C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\Tor Browser2\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\torrc.orig.1" 
14 sept. 2016 9:48:20 a. m..800 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server

14 sept. 2016 9:48:21 a. m..100 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server

14 sept. 2016 10:48:36 a. m..200 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 10; recommendation warn; host 75F1992FD3F403E9C082A5815EB5D12934CDF46C at 46.101.237.246:9001)

14 sept. 2016 10:48:36 a. m..200 [WARN] 10 connections have failed:

14 sept. 2016 10:48:36 a. m..200 [WARN]  10 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE

14 sept. 2016 10:48:58 a. m..200 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150

14 sept. 2016 10:48:58 a. m..200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.

14 sept. 2016 10:48:58 a. m..200 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150

14 sept. 2016 10:48:58 a. m..200 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.

Comment: What happens if you set it to use bridges? (obfs4 or meek?)

Comment: I asked the Bridges, but I never got the mail, so use one I found on the web, but when I want to set, Tor tells me that they are invalid.

Comment: Probably don't use one you found on the web. You need to email from Yahoo, Gmail or RiseUp.

Comment: See: https://www.torproject.org/docs/bridges#AddTorNotWorks

Comment: I tried with de Bridges that you said but nothing happed. The log said this:
DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server

Comment: Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
[WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (Connection timed out [WSAETIMEDOUT ]; TIMEOUT; count 3; recommendation warn; host 081DA1FDD0551277C2B871C8EFFE76D0EF0C27A9 at 92.37.170.115:443) 
[WARN] 2 connections have failed: 
[WARN]  1 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
[WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150

Comment: [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150